# Migrating from guava.Optional to java8.Optional

Tags: java, java-8, guava, option-type

Trying to migration guava Optional implementation to java 8 Optional. Got into this issue which I am not able understand.
Here is how my method looks:

```
public Optional<Entity> getEntity(String input) {
   try{
    final Entity obj = otherClass.verifyEntity(input);
    return Optional.of(obj);
   } catch(Exception e) {
   }
   return Optional.empty();
}
```

It looks very straight forward but I am keep getting this compilation error which says `Change return type to Optional<Entity`.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Since you are dealing with two classes named `Optional`, check, which `Optional` is in your imports. If your method implements or overrides another `getEntity` method, check that the overridden method uses the same `Optional`.

Comment: Actually the code works http://ideone.com/T389Tu

Comment: Unless you have said conflicts between different `Optional` types, it should work. Even a simplified `try{ return Optional.of(otherClass.verifyEntity(input)); } catch(Exception e) { return Optional.empty(); }` should work.

Comment: Yup! Just the Super library class. It is causing the conflict. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `return Optional.<Entity>empty();`

Comment: I think he meant `return Optional<Entity>.empty()`